# MongoDB: How to return random elements without Linq? (MongoDB, C#)

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a request like this to the database:

```
db.collection.Find(filters).Limit(limit);
```

filters created: `filters` - is of type `FilterDefinition`

how can I make a request that will return me a random selection of elements with these filters - `filters`?

i know there is a way with Linq - `AsQueryable().Sample()` - but I cannot figure out how to use my `filters` - with type `FilterDefinition`

can there be another way, without Linq?

Comment: Are you OK if the same document appears multiple times in the output?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the aggregation framework to achieve this, it won't change how you've built up your filter as you can just use this within a `$match` stage.

There's currently no type-safe way to create a sample stage (this is on the Jira backlog [CSHARP-2659](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-2659)), however, you can just use the normal JSON syntax.

```
var client = new MongoClient();

var db = client.GetDatabase("test");
var collection = db.GetCollection<Person>("people");

// Setup some data
var people = Enumerable.Range(1, 100)
    .Select(x => new Person {Name = $"Person {x}", Age = x});

await collection.InsertManyAsync(people);

var filter = Builders<Person>.Filter.Gt(x => x.Age, 18);
var sampleSize = 10;

// Run aggregation query with a sample stage ($sample)
var personSample = await collection.Aggregate()
    .Match(filter)
    .AppendStage<Person>($@"{{ $sample: {{ size: {sampleSize} }} }}")
    .ToListAsync();

// Output sample
foreach (var person in personSample)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{person.Name}, Age: {person.Age}");
}

// Example output, note only 10 items all with the matching filter.
// Person 84, Age: 84
// Person 97, Age: 97
// Person 35, Age: 35
// Person 40, Age: 40
// Person 69, Age: 69
// Person 28, Age: 28
// Person 79, Age: 79
// Person 31, Age: 31
// Person 20, Age: 20
// Person 64, Age: 64
```

You can find more information on $sample stage on the MongoDB documentation, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/

Answer (score 1):

you could do it with an aggregation.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/

Answer (score 0):

found a way through `Inject`, can also do it like this:

```
db.collection.AsQueryable().Where(x => filters.Inject()).Sample(limit);
```