# Why is $sample missing in MongoDB .NET Driver()?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using MongoDB.Driver 2.11.6 version, I installed it with NuGet package manager in visual studio 2019. I wrote this method:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> ExploreUsers(ObjectId id)
{
    ObjectId currentUser = id;

    var db = _mongoService.GetDb;
    var userCollection = db.GetCollection<User>("Users");

    // Get CurrentUser:
    var filterContacts = Builders<User>.Filter.Eq(u => u.Id, currentUser);
    User currentDocument = (await userCollection.FindAsync<User>(filterContacts))
                                                .First<User>();
    // Get Id of Users in Contacts:
    var contactsArray = currentDocument.Contacts.Select(x => x.OtherUserId);

    // Get Users:
    var filterPom = Builders<User>.Filter.Nin("_id", contactsArray);
    var filter = Builders<User>.Filter.And(!filterContacts & filterPom);
    var users = await userCollection.Aggregate<User>().Match(filter)
                                                      .Limit(20)
                                                      .ToListAsync();
                                                    //.ToString();

    return Ok(users.Select(x => new UserDTO { ObjectId = x.Id.ToString(), 
                                              Username = x.Username }));
}
```

In this method I first find `User`(I will call him `currentUser`) with `Id` from argument of function, `User` have property `Contacts` of type `List<Contact>` and information that is important in this method from `Contact` is `OtherUserId` and this is `Id` of `User` in same collection and `contactsArray` is of type List that stores information. Last query returns 20 or less `Users` from collection that is not in `Contacts` of `currentUser`.

But I want this query:

```
db.getCollection("Users")
    .aggregate([
                { "$match" : { "_id" : 
                                       { "$nin" : [ObjectId("60286f9f5e7da329ba5eb813"), 
                                                  ObjectId("60286f9f5e7da329ba5eb813"), 
                                                  ObjectId("602a5b642e156713e69d0a20")] 
                                       } 
                             } 
                }, 
                { "$sample" : {size: 1} }
            ])
```

Only difference is that `Sample()` doesn't exist and in [documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.11/reference/driver/crud/reading/#project). Is there way to get query I want using my version of MongoDB.Driver(2.11.6)?

Also before this query I first call `FindAsync<User>` and then perform simple LINQ query to get `IEnumerable<ObjectId>` that I use in last query. Is there way to let DBMS do this for me? If there is a way how to modify my current query (it is not important for me is it code in **C#** or **mongo shell query**)?

## Edit

I found answer on first question on link from comment: [Random elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63346252/mongodb-how-to-return-random-elements-without-linq-mongodb-c/63360112#63360112). So instead of  `Limit(20)` I added:

```cs
AppendStage<User>($@"{{ $sample: {{ size: {sampleSize} }} }}")
```

where `sampleSize` is `int`.

**Documentation**:

- [Driver Documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.11/reference/driver/crud/reading/#aggregation)(example of usage in last example Text search)
- [API Documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/search.html?SearchText=appendstage)

Comment: This answer might help you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/63360112/4079967

Comment: Thank you, it's working with `AppendStage`. This question looks similar, but I was searching for $sample and couldn't see it.

Comment: For the record, the performance of $sample is pretty horrible.